# Sample and allow duplicates, but not when they appear twice in a row

Tags: r

Given 4 numerical objects, e.g.

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=11:15, d=16:20)
```

How would one proceed to sample values from these objects, allowing duplicates while not getting the same value twice in a row?

Not ok:

```
7, 3, 3, 12, 17 (two 3's in a row)
```

Ok:

```
17, 3, 7, 2, 7 (duplicates, but no value appears twice in a row)
```

Comment: Do rejection sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very manually, you can test whether each number equals all other numbers and test whether there are two `TRUE`'s in a row, and based on that, repeat the sampling until the condition is `FALSE`.

You can implement in a funcion like this.

```
sampler <- function(number_sample) {
  x <- sample(1:number_sample, replace = TRUE)
  pre_test <- lapply(x, function(single_number) diff(which(single_number == x)) == 1)
  test <- any(sapply(pre_test, any))

  if (test) sampler(number_sample) else x
}

sampler(100)
sampler(10)
```

This, naturally, becomes very slow with high numbers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative function based on sample().

```
custom.sampling <- function(pool, elems) {
  # arg check
  if ((!is.vector(pool) )|
    elems < 2)
    stop("Bad params")

  #init and proceed
  tmp <- c(1,1)
  while (sum(table(tmp) == 2) >0 ){
    tmp <- sample(pool, size = elems, replace = T)
  }
  return(tmp)
}

pool <- 0:9
elems <- 5
custom.sampling(pool, elems)
```

Comment: This uses table() to quickly check and prevent duplictes.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
values <- 1:4 #values to sample from
len <- 20 #number of samples
samp <- sample(values,1) #initialise variable
length(samp) <- len
sapply(2:len, function(i) samp[i] <<- sample(setdiff(values, samp[i-1]), 1))

samp
[1] 2 1 4 1 4 3 2 4 3 1 3 1 4 3 4 1 3 1 4 2
```

The `<<-` operator changes the value of `samp` in the global environment as the `sapply` loop progresses, so each time it samples from `values` excluding the previous value.