# Random sampling in R without direct repetition and exact quantity of each number

Tags: r, random, sequence, sample

How can I randomly sample the color order of 368 images using 4 colors that

- should not be repeated directly *("red" "red" "blue" would not be ok, but "red" "blue" "red" would be)*
- should each appear with an equal quantity (each 92 times because 368/4 = 92)?

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881082/sample-and-allow-duplicates-but-not-when-they-appear-twice-in-a-row), I have already managed the sampling without direct repetition:

```
library("dplyr")
set.seed(340)
values <- c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow")
len <- 368 # number of samples
samp <- sample(values, 1) # initialise variable
cols <- sapply(2:len, function(i) samp[i] <<- sample(setdiff(values, samp[i-1]), 1, replace = TRUE))
table(cols) # colors appear 94, 92, 88, 93 times
```

I tried building a for-loop that samples until the exact numbers are reached with `if(table(cols)[1:4] == 92)`, but it didn't work and after doing a lot of research, I still don't know how to proceed. I would be really thankful for tips and help!

Comment: Do you know Markov chains?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent , not really unfortunately, especially not with R - some things do sound familiar but I have trouble "translating" my special case in a Markov chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. The idea is to create the sorted vector first (`seqc`). Then for each iteration, the algorithm sample one value out of the possible values (i.e. all except the previous one in the vector).

```r
seqc <- rep(values, each = 92)
vec <- sample(seqc, 1)
seqc <- seqc[-match(vec, seqc)]
for (i in 2:368){
  vec[i] <- sample(seqc[seqc != vec[i - 1]], 1)
  seqc <- seqc[-match(vec[i], seqc)]
}
```

output

```r
head(vec)
# [1] "red"    "blue"   "red"    "yellow" "blue"   "yellow"

table(vec)
#vec
#  blue  green    red yellow 
#    92     92     92     92
```

It might throw an error, because the algorithm might not work as expected. In that case, rerun it until it works; it usually takes no more than 3 iterations for it to work.

Comment: Wow, thank you for your quick reply! (That's my first question here and I'm amazed.) It worked perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Markov chain.

```r
library(markovchain)

# states
statesNames <- c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow")
# transition matrix: each state can go to another state with probability 1/3
tmatrix <- rbind(
  c(0, 1/3, 1/3, 1/3),
  c(1/3, 0, 1/3, 1/3),
  c(1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3),
  c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0)
)
# Markov chain
chain <- new("markovchain", states = statesNames, transitionMatrix = tmatrix)

# sample the Markov chain
rmarkovchain(n = 10, chain)
#  "red"    "green"  "red"    "yellow" "red"    "yellow" "red"    "blue"   "yellow" "blue"
```

The graph of the Markov chain:

```
plot(chain)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane, I learned so much today.

Comment: I like the approach with markov chains. Would it be possible to change the probability of a given color to zero once it was sampled the maximum number of times (N = 92)?

Comment: Another question: a bigger sample size (n=368)  and exactly your code does not produce equal color numbers... as the sampling is based only on the probabilities of .33 or 0 - would it be really possible to produce an equal number of 92 for each color? (just asking out of interest)

Answer (score 1):

Since we must have 92 elements of each color, I'd say we can just put them all together in one vector, shuffle them, and then solve the conflicts (i.e. colors next to each other) by putting duplicated color elsewhere (e.g. at the end of the vector).

```
set.seed(1) 

# Declare all the colors we need
colors_total=rep(c("red","blue","green","yellow"),each=92)
# Shuffle them
col_vector=sample(colors_total)

# Create a vector to know if each color has a duplicate on the right
side_by_side<-(col_vector[-length(col_vector)]==col_vector[-1])
# Find the first duplicate
index_first_side_by_side=which(side_by_side)

# While there are duplicates, do:
while(length(index_first_side_by_side)>0){
  # Get the color to put elsewhere
  duplicated_color=col_vector[index_first_side_by_side]
  
  # Check the colors from the duplicate element to the end of col_vector
  # If it is always the same unique color, we cannot just put the duplicate element in the end
  # in order to avoid infinite loop
  if(length(unique(col_vector[index_first_side_by_side:length(col_vector)]))==1){
    # Decide a random place to put the duplicate
    r=runif(n=1,min=1,max=index_first_side_by_side-1)
    # Remove it from col_vector
    col_vector=c(col_vector[-index_first_side_by_side])
    # Add it at position r
    col_vector=c(col_vector[1:(r-1)],
                 duplicated_color,
                 col_vector[(r+1):length(col_vector)])
  } else { 
    # Otherwise can put duplicate in the end of vector
    col_vector=c(col_vector[-index_first_side_by_side],duplicated_color)
  }
  # Check if we have same colors side by side now
  side_by_side<-(col_vector[-length(col_vector)]==col_vector[-1])
  index_first_side_by_side=which(side_by_side)
}

col_vector
```

Comment: Thank you @A.FC! Your explanations are really helpful and your approach worked, too! As the other answer is more similar to my previously used approach, I'll mark that one as the answer but I still am very thankful for your idea and help and will look more deeply into it.